# function(x) in R: writing a "function" without defining a function?

Tags: r, function

I have come across this concept a couple of times, but don't know the name for it so cannot google it to learn more. Basically, when looking through functions or even simple commands others have written I will often see something similar to this:

```
apply(dataset, 1:2, function(x) 10 * x)
```

In this case, I was able to figure out that somehow this "fake function" **function(x)** would just multiply each element of the dataset by 10. This seems like a useful feature, but I'm still not certain when or how you use it. Is it really a function? Or does it just work within the apply family of functions? Is there a name for this thing?

Comment: It's called an anonymous function. That should help with Googling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are called "anonymous functions", and yes, they are real function objects, which just happen to have not been assigned to any symbol before being used.

Here's the relevant bit from the [R language documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Writing-functions):

> Generally functions are assigned to symbols but they don’t need to be. The value returned by the call to function is a function. If this is not given a name it is referred to as an anonymous function. Anonymous functions are most frequently used as arguments to other functions such as the apply family or outer.

Although they are most typically used in `*apply()` functions, they need not be, as can be seen here, for example

```
(function(x,y){x*y + x/y})(2,5)
# [1] 10.4
```

Answer (score 7):

As of **R 4.1.0**, it is now possible to natively use `\(x) {}` instead of `function(x) {}` for anonymous function.

The apply code can be written as

```
dataset |>
    apply(1:2, \(x) {10 * x})
```

Comment: Not only for anonymous functions.

Answer (score 5):

You mean a [lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) (anonymous function)? You could put something like this in your `~/.Rprofile` file:

```
`{` <- function(...)
  base::`{`(
    if (length(sys.calls()) >= 4 &&
        identical(as.character(sys.call()[[1]]), "{") &&
        identical(as.character(sys.call(-4)[[1]]), "{"))
      base::`{`(fn <- new('function'),
        formals(fn) <- alist(x=), body(fn) <- sys.call(), fn)
    else eval.parent(substitute(base::`{`(...)))
  )
```

Then you can do things like:

```
sapply(1:10, {{x + 5}})
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

This is closer to languages like Ruby or Coffeescript which don't need to invoke a keyword to make a lambda (there they use `->` but this is already taken in R so I used double braces). I just came up with this so if there are bugs let me know.

Comment: This probably doesn’t help OP at all but it’s an interesting idea. Myself, [I’m partial to overloading `->`.](https://gist.github.com/klmr/25dc765211c59bb749b0)

Comment: My problem with that is that most of the people I work with actually use `->` for assignment when random munging in console - easier than going back to the beginning

Comment: I guess you could turn `%>%` into `base::\`<-\``?

Comment: It is an interesting idea, though I'd suggest taking care when redefining such a fundamental R symbol. For instance, `system.time(replicate(1e6, {1+1}))` goes from 3.7 seconds to 37.1 seconds on my box, before and after your redefinition of `{`.

Comment: Actually overloading `->` also makes `<-` unusable for assignment. I use `=` throughout. It’s a price worth paying for a good lambda syntax.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yep, it's the `sys.call()`. I don't think porting to C would work. Mostly just an interesting idea -- this kind of thing should only be done in closed environments where you know hard computation is not happening (like `source(..., local = put_the_definition_in_here)`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Actually you could overload `(` in tandem with `<-` to create lambdas that work exactly like in Coffeescript

Comment: @KonradRudolph -- Yeah, I more than half-agree. The currently-required syntax is so cumbersome I typically just define a function outside to  pass into `lapply` et al., just to improve the code's readability.

Comment: Yep, someday I hope to understand more than one quarter of what was said here :) sounds interesting...

Comment: @Robert This doesn’t work: you can overload `(` but you cannot make the syntax `(x, y)` valid in R, nor `(x, y) -> x + y` (I’d love to be corrected). The best you can do is use `~` to define arguments, thus getting `x ~ y -> x + y`. [I’ve updated the Gist accordingly.](https://gist.github.com/klmr/25dc765211c59bb749b0)