# Is it "bad" to define closures at the top level, only to be called inside a function? If so: alternatives?

Tags: python, r, language-agnostic, scope

*I'm tagging this one "language-agnostic" because I'm asking about what seems to be a general principle, but I'm using R and Python as my examples.*

I've written an R script along the lines of this MWE:

```
## Does not work:

plus_i <- function(x) x + i
times_i <- function(x) x * i

loop_i <- function(x) {
    for(i in 1:2) {
        x <- plus_i(x)
        x <- times_i(x)
    }
    x
}

loop_i(3)
```

but it fails with `Error in plus_i(x) : object 'i' not found` because of R's lexical scoping. I couldn't even hack my way around it with `eval`.

The Python equivalent also fails:

```
## Does not work:

def plus_i(x):
    return x + i

def times_i(x):
    return x * i

def loop_i(x):
    # mutable objects beware
    for i in [1, 2]:
        x = plus_i(x)
        x = times_i(x)
    return x

loop_i(3)
```

In my understanding, these programs would work in a *dynamically* scoped language, but R and Python are both statically/lexically scoped. If that's the case, then is it somehow anti-paradigmatic or otherwise "bad" to write R and Python code like this? Is this just a matter of "explicit is better than implicit", or does it go deeper?

*edit: it seems that, indeed, it goes deeper. apparently [lexical scoping is an inherent feature of closures](http://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/lexical-scope-and-function-closures-in-r/). the question still applies.*

Note that `plus_i` and `times_i` are not used outside of `loop_i` in the program. But what I *don't* want to do is define `plus_i` and `times_i` inside `loop_i`, because I think it seriously hurts the readability of the code (which is not as simple as in this example).  What I also don't want to do is make `i` an explicit function argument, because there are several such `i`'s and again it seems to make the code less readable and much more difficult to debug (by having to keep track of what is defined locally and what is passed in).

Another alternative would be to create a new environment, define `plus_i` and `times_i` inside it, and then pass it to `loop_i`. But this still feels like an off-label use of environments. *edit: or, reassign `environment(plus_i) <- environment()`*

Comment: I don't understand your last comment: "this still feels like an off-label use of environments". There is no way for `plus_i` or `times_i` to know where `i` comes from without providing it as an argument or *modifying its parent environment*.

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering about is if there's a reason I _shouldn't_ mess with functions' calling environments. I called it "off-label" because it seemed like an abuse of the feature, but based on these answers it seems like this is actually _the_ intended purpose of environment modifications.

Comment: The environment I was modifying below wasn't the calling environment, since you have no control over where your function gets called from. Actually, that is basically the answer: if you provide a function that is "incomplete" by referencing symbols it cannot find in its argument list or default parent environment, it will be much harder for others to use. Imagine if `plus_i` was several dozen lines of code with one use of `i` snuck in somewhere; how would someone know the function depends on `i`?

Comment: Why not `plus <- function(x, i) x + i`?

Comment: @peterhurford that's addressed explicitly in my post and in the comments to an answer.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski Very true. I hadn't thought of that because in my case each function leans heavily on `i` and it's everywhere in the source code. You should put that in your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read through [Hadley's guide on functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html), you'll understand there are four environments to keep in mind for every function:

- The defining environment - Where the function's code is stored.
- The calling environment - What environment the function was called from.
- The parent environment - Where the function looks for symbols if it is a closure.
- The local scope - Ad hoc environment created every time you execute the function, whose
     parent is the environment described above.

In this case, you are defining `plus_i` and `times_i` outside of the loop, so their parent environment will be the global environment -- this is where they look for additional symbols (like `i`), and will not find them. To nudge the functions along, you could force the matter by telling them where to look.

```
 plus_i <- function(x) x + i
 times_i <- function(x) x * i

 loop_i <- function(x) {
     environment(plus_i) <- environment()  # Look "here", in the local scope
     environment(times_i) <- environment() # of loop_i, for i!
     for(i in 1:2) {
         x <- plus_i(x)
         x <- times_i(x)
     }
     x
 }

 loop_i(3)
 # [1] 12
```

Note this will not inadvertently change the parent environment of either function, because R is implicitly creating a copy of each function within `loop_i` due to the assignment.

In general, however, not specifying `i` as an argument is a bad idea: if you provide a function that is "incomplete" by referencing symbols it cannot find in its argument list or default parent environment, it will be much harder for others to use. Imagine if `plus_i` was several dozen lines of code with one use of `i` snuck in somewhere; how would someone know the function depends on `i`? For small scripts it may be OK but it would not be good development hygiene long-term.

Comment: I've actually skimmed that chapter, although I didn't realize `environment()` without an argument would return the current environment. Thanks for a working workaround, but that isn't really what I'm after here.

Comment: I would argue that what you are after isn't an intention of functional programming. It is very confusing to define a closure that isn't, well... closed. You should be defining `plus_i` and `times_i` within the function as [lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596540/functionx-in-r-writing-a-function-without-defining-a-function) or be making `i` an argument -- which it *is*, since it's a requisite input to the function!

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to *R*, but for *Python*, there would be a couple of different options...

To your top-level question about whether it's "bad" to define top-level functions and then call them from other functions, I would say no -- that's done frequently in *Python*.

The issue here with the code that you've written is that you want the top-level functions to be aware of the `i` variable that is declared within another function. In your code above, `i` is only defined in the `loop_i` function. The other functions have no awareness of them, and you'll get a `NameError` exception about it not being defined when trying to access it from one of the top-level functions.

The most straightforward thing to do with the code you have now is probably to declare a `global` variable named `i`, above the top-level functions, so the top-level functions will then be aware of it.

The other option that comes to mind, and the one I would probably use, would be to define a *class* containing the class-level variable `i`, and then define the top-level functions as methods of that *class* instead. They would then be able to access `i` via `ClassName.i`. I generally code all of my *Python* using a class anyway, so this wouldn't be much of a departure code-wise.

If you want to keep it more *C*-like, then the `global` is probably the best option, although global variables certainly come with their own complexities.

Here's one possible `global` version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def plus_i(x):
    return x + i

def times_i(x):
    return x * i

def loop_i(x):
    global i
    # mutable objects beware
    for i in [1, 2]:
        x = plus_i(x)
        print("plus_i x: {0}".format(x))

        x = times_i(x)
        print("times_i x: {0}".format(x))

    return x

loop_i(3)
```

And here's one possible `class` version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class ScopeTest:
    i = None

    def plus_i(self, x):
        return x + ScopeTest.i

    def times_i(self, x):
        return x * ScopeTest.i

    def loop_i(self, x):
        # mutable objects beware
        for ScopeTest.i in [1, 2]:
            x = self.plus_i(x)
            print("plus_i x: {0}".format(x))

            x = self.times_i(x)
            print("times_i x: {0}".format(x))

        return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    st = ScopeTest()
    st.loop_i(3)
```

And they both output:

```
plus_i x: 4
times_i x: 4
plus_i x: 6
times_i x: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def plus_i(x, i):
    return x + i

def times_i(x, i):
    return x * i

def loop_i(x):
    # mutable objects beware
    for i in [1, 2]:
        x = plus_i(x, i)
        x = times_i(x, i)
    return x

loop_i(3)
```

typically for languages like this, you pass i as a function argument as shown above.

the advantage of doing so is that it makes the code referential transparent, which makes it easier to verify and understand its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an "i" argument to the functions they behave as expected:

```
 plus_i <- function(x,i) x + i
 times_i <- function(x,i) x * i

 loop_i <- function(x) {
     for(i in 1:2) {
         x <- plus_i(x,i)
         x <- times_i(x,i)
     }
     x
 }

 loop_i(3)
#[1] 12
```

The use of assignment of an environment is really having exactly the same effect as providing "i" as a formal argument. It just means that the "local"-"i" will be found.

Comment: I addressed this in the question: "What I also don't want to do is make `i` an explicit function argument, because there are several such `i`'s and again it seems to make the code less readable and much more difficult to debug (by having to keep track of what is defined locally and what is passed in)."

Comment: @ssdecontrol "there are several such `i`'s" --> this might be a good point at which to use more meaningful variable names, or split your function into smaller units.

Comment: The search path will find the most recently defined "i", i.e. the one inside the for()-loop, so your effort to avoid using an argument is not necessary.

Comment: @HongOoi neither of those concerns apply to the real code I'm using. The variable names are extremely descriptive and the functions are very simple.

Comment: @BondedDust I'm not avoiding the explicit-argument approach because of the search path, I'm avoiding it because it makes it difficult for _me_, the programmer, to keep track of what is defined where.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Then you shouldn't have problems with defining your argument list appropriately....

Comment: @ssdecontrol: You are fooling yourself if you think that manipulating the environment is any different than this method.