# How to subset data frames in a list by row number range with lapply?

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a list of data frames. I'd like to extract the first 248 rows of every data frame, then bind them together into one single data frame.

`allData` is the list of data frames. I've tried to use `lapply` with `subset` but I don't know how to refer to row numbers in there. It seems the "subset" argument of the `subset` function only accept logical vector.

```
temp <- lapply(allData, subset, subset = (row.names(allData) <= 248))
```

This code is my idea which does not work, because `row.names(allData)` actually only applies to the list itself, not the data frames. How to refer to the row numbers of each data frame then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R, we can do

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(allData, function(x) x[1:248, ]))
```

OR with `purrr`

```
purrr::map_dfr(allData, ~.[1:248, ])
```

---

Using reproducible example with `mtcars` data and subsetting first 5 rows.

```
allData <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
do.call(rbind, lapply(allData, function(x) x[1:5, ]))

#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4          21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710         22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive     21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout  18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Mazda RX41         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag1     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 7101        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive1    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout1 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Comment: Nice solution with base package. I had to look up the `function(x)` part, which turns out to be called an "anonymous function". More info here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596540/functionx-in-r-writing-a-function-without-defining-a-function)

Comment: For base, it may be simpler to do ```lapply(allData, `[`, 1:248, )``` with the ```do.call()```.  But, the anonymous function is probably easier to follow along.

Comment: @Cole yes...that is definitely shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Another `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

allData %>% 
  map_df(function(x) x %>% slice(1:10))
```

---

Since the OP didn't provide sample data, we can use `iris` dataset:

```
allData <- list(iris1 = iris[1:50,], # create a list with iris
                iris2 = iris[51:100,], 
                iris3 = iris[101:150,])

allData %>% 
  map_df(~.[1:10,])

## (first 10 rows)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
#6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
#7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
#8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
#9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
#10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
```